# PIC assembly code simplify

Tags: pic, assembly, 8051

I need to convert the following PIC assembly code (below) to an 8051 assembly. It is an inline assembly code. Actually, I intend to convert it to C. I am not familiar with the PIC MCU so I do not understand much of what happens. If I can an understanding of each instruction, I will try and input the equivalent assembly. Or better still, I will appreciate if I can get an equivalent 8051 assembly code of it. "toRotate" is a 32 bit variable. Thanks

```
    _asm
    movlb toRotate
    bcf STATUS,0,0
    btfsc toRotate+3,7,1
    bsf STATUS,0,0
    rlcf toRotate+0,1,1
    rlcf toRotate+1,1,1
    rlcf toRotate+2,1,1
    rlcf toRotate+3,1,1
    _endasm
```

This is the entire code below.....I really want to know what is done here. My intention is to convert it to C language.

```
DWORD leftRotateDWORD(DWORD val, BYTE bits)
{
    BYTE i, t;
    DWORD_VAL toRotate;
    toRotate.Val = val;

    for(i = bits; i >= 8u; i -= 8)
    {
        t = toRotate.v[3];
        toRotate.v[3] = toRotate.v[2];
        toRotate.v[2] = toRotate.v[1];
        toRotate.v[1] = toRotate.v[0];
        toRotate.v[0] = t;
    }

    for(; i != 0u; i--)
    {
        _asm
        movlb toRotate
        bcf STATUS,0,0
        btfsc toRotate+3,7,1
        bsf STATUS,0,0
        rlcf toRotate+0,1,1
        rlcf toRotate+1,1,1
        rlcf toRotate+2,1,1
        rlcf toRotate+3,1,1
        _endasm

    }
    return toRotate.Val;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code snippet is for a PIC 18.  It is a naively written routine to rotate the 32 bit variable **toRotate** left one bit.  Here is the code with some annotation:

```
         movlb   toRotate    ;set bank for access to target variable
         bcf     STATUS, C   ;init bit to shift in to 0
         btfsc   toRotate+3, 7 ;bit to shift in really is 0 ?
         bsf     STATUS, C   ;no, set it to 1
         rlcf    toRotate+0, 1 ;do the left shift by one bit
         rlcf    toRotate+1, 1
         rlcf    toRotate+2, 1
         rlcf    toRotate+3, 1
```

Comment: Thanks Olin. I am actually working on an HASH algorithm. I got this code from the MicroChip TCP/IP Stack. But I want to believe that i can used it for an 8 bit MCU, because I am much of an 8051 guy. Thanks

Comment: Please I edited the question with the code. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As Olin Lathrop said, it's a 32-bit left rotate.

Many compilers ([a](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Simple_math#rotate_right)) recognize this idiom as a "32-bit rotate":

```
DWORD leftRotateDWORD(DWORD x, BYTE shift){
    y = (x << shift) | (x >> (32 - shift));
}
```

Those compilers will emit a single 32 bit rotate instruction on processors that have such an instruction,
or a highly optimized sequence on other processors.

You might save a lot of time in testing and debugging by
using one of the freely available implementations of SHA256 or SHA-3 proposed algorithms:
( [a](http://www.aarongifford.com/computers/sha.html) [b](http://freebsd.active-venture.com/FreeBSD-srctree/newsrc/crypto/sha2/sha2.c.html) [c](http://www.ouah.org/ogay/sha2/) [d](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sha256#Implementations_in_common_languages) [e](http://www-pequan.lip6.fr/~gouicem/pdf/note_to_SHA3_mailing_list.pdf) )